# How to get the current angle of a QPolygonF item in a QGraphicsScene item?

Tags: c++, qt, rotation

I'm want to implement seek behavior with an itme rotation towards the direction point.
All manipulations I'm making in QGraphicsView with QGraphicsScene and a QPolygonF item.
[image]

I do not know the current angle of the `QPolygonF item` to subtract from the target point angle. How can i make it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`QGraphicsPolygonItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicspolygonitem.html) and `rotate` that towards the target.  (To determine the angle, take the `item.pos() - point.pos()` and calculate it's arctangent).

You should really not bother with rotating the painter as you do in the other question your refer to, but with rotating the `Vehicle`, which should be a `QGraphicsSceneItem`.  The GraphicsScene takes care of the transformations.

Next to that, probably the rotation angle should be the `atan(...) *360/twopi`.

Comment: Please load my project or check this question, I do not know what to do else. I was doing exactly what you said. [Here it is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513841/how-to-rotate-a-triangle-apex-point-towards-the-point-in-qt?noredirect=1#comment56768662_34513841)